# Find code in text without specific format

Tags: r

If I would like to detect R code in a free text is there any possibility to detect it? It is exist in the text like simple text there is no format for this.

Example

> here we say something and the code is just as this text
>
> library(dplyr)
> library(stringr)
> dd %>% filter(str_count(text, " ") >= 3)

Answer (score 1):

you way to go would be with regex (regular expressions). one option it the rebus package to make this a bit easier:

```
library(dplyr)
library(rebus)
library(stringi)

# example data
df <- dplyr::tibble(id <- c(1, 2),
                    text <- c('here we say something and the code is just as this text  library(dplyr) library(stringr) dd %>% filter(str_count(text, " ") >= 3', 
                              'here we say something and the code is just as this text'))

# pattern to detect: 'libaray(asdfasdf)' or '%>%' )
pattern <- or("library(" %R% one_or_more(ALPHA) %R% ")", "%>%")

# calculations
df %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(DETECTED = stringi::stri_detect_regex(text, pattern))
```

This will create a new column "DETECTED" which will be true if eighter a library(asfas) or %>% was detected in the column "text". Maybe you want to include more options in the pattern as possibly some users will not make a library call or work with the pipe operator. You could possibly include the assignment operator "<-" or even the "::" for function calls in R which are commonly used and should not appear in "normal" text.